# Setting android text style programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to set this style of a text view:

```
style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
```

I searched and found more solutions about that, but I can't use

tv_style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

with a code like this:

```
private void makeSelectable(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            makeSelectable((ViewGroup) child);
        } else if (child instanceof TextView) {
            ((TextView) child)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tv_style, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following:

```
Error: getLayoutInflater can only be called from within the same library group
```

Comment: Where is that code, exactly? That is, what kind of class is it in?

Comment: @MikeM. i use that into fragment

Comment: Ah, OK. That `getLayoutInflater()` method isn't accessible in `Fragment`. If you're calling `makeSelectable()` from `onCreateView()`, you can pass it the `LayoutInflater` that's passed into `onCreateView()`. Otherwise, you can get one some other way; e.g., `LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())`. However, it's not really clear what you're trying to do there. That is, this line doesn't really make sense: `((TextView) child)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tv_style, null);`. If you're trying to set that style on an already-inflated `TextView`, there's a `setTextAppearance()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. i'm trying to find how can i set `style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"` to textview simply, `((TextView) child)` in my part of code created programical and i dont have that into `xml` and i can't set style, your solution is not clear for me and i'm trying to test that

Comment: It would be like `((TextView) child).setTextAppearance(R.style.Base_TextAppearance_AppCompat_Body1);`. You might have to pass a `Context` in that method, too, depending on your min API level.

Answer (score 0):

please Try

```
((ViewGroup) child).inflate(R.layout.tv_style, null);
```